# quartz 2.2.1+jboss EAP 6.4 ClassNotFoundException oracle.sql.BLOB

Tags: jboss, oracle11g, jboss7.x, quartz-scheduler, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to build a quartz scheduler ejb app and have it deployed on JBOSS EAP 6.4. Additionally, I'm trying to do so using quartz JDBC jobstore using an Oracle 11g database.

Now, the problem is that whenever I try to schedule a job, I get this exception :

```
18:45:01,024 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."com.hp.heimdall.jar".component.QuartzBootstraper.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."com.hp.heimdall.jar".component.QuartzBootstraper.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:164) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:135) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 6 more


Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: JBAS014580: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:188)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:282)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:367)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:70) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:162) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 11 more


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/sql/BLOB
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate.writeDataToBlob(OracleDelegate.java:592)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate.insertJobDetail(OracleDelegate.java:183)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$2.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:1062)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3703)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3701)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1058)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:886)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249)
    at Quartz_POC.com.hp.heimdall.QuartzAvailabilityTest.runTest(QuartzAvailabilityTest.java:69)
    at Quartz_POC.com.hp.heimdall.QuartzBootstraper.init(QuartzBootstraper.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:280)
    ... 20 more


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB from [Module "org.quartz:main" from local module loader @9e89d68 (finder: local module finder @3b192d32 (roots: C:\Users\abdelgam\EAP-6.4.0\modules,C:\Users\abdelgam\EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 48 more
```

### **Configurations**

**Installed Modules**

In my JBOSS_HOME/modules I installed the following modules:

1. quartz 2.2.1
   module.xml :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
>
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.quartz">
>
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="quartz-2.2.1.jar"/>
>     </resources>
>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="javax.api"/>
>         <module name="org.slf4j"/>
>         <module name="com.c3p0"/>
>     </dependencies>
> </module>
> ```

2. oracle jdbc driver module.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
>
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
>     </resources>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="javax.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
>     </dependencies>
> </module>
> ```

3. c3p0 module.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
>
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.c3p0">
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="c3p0-0.9.1.1-jdk1.3.jar"/>
>         <resource-root path="c3p0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.1.1.jar"/>
>     </resources>
>     <dependencies>
>         <module name="javax.api"/>
>         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
>         <module name="org.hibernate"/>
>     </dependencies>
> </module>
> ```

**quartz.properties**

```
# Default Properties file for use by StdSchedulerFactory
# to create a Quartz Scheduler Instance, if a different
# properties file is not explicitly specified.
#

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export: false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy: false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction: false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

#============================================================================
# Configure JdbcJobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
#
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================


org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.jndiURL=java:jboss/datasources/quartzDS
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>

   <deployment>

      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.quartz" export="TRUE" />
         <module name="com.c3p0" export="TRUE" />
         <module name="com.oracle" export="TRUE" />
      </dependencies>

   </deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Quartz-POC</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.hp.heimdall</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>com.hp.heimdall</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>org.quartz export, com.c3p0 export, com.oracle export</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Server Config "standalone.xml"**

Datasource

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/quartzDS" pool-name="quartzDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>OracleJDBCDriver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>quartz_user</user-name>
                        <password>quartz_user</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Drivers

```
<drivers>
                    <driver name="OracleJDBCDriver" module="com.oracle">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this ClassNotFoundException??

Comment: Try add `com.oracle` dependency to the quartz module definition

Comment: Hi Federico, I truly appreciate your response. This actually fixed the problem. But the question remains, why should I add it as an explicit dependency in quartz's module definition? Although, I did add the oracle driver module as as part of my deployment structure.

Comment: @Amr Where else would quartz get the oracle driver module if you don't add the dependency? jboss-deployment-structure is your app-level dependencies, but quartz module is a module: modules cannot see dependencies that are app-level.

Comment: @Federico, million thanks. You're the man!!! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:

```
svn.terracotta.org/svn/quartz/trunk/quartz-oracle/src/main/java/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/oracle/OracleDelegate.java
```

the source there in line 592+ look like

```
if (blob instanceof oracle.sql.BLOB) { // is it an oracle blob?
            ((oracle.sql.BLOB) blob).putBytes(1, data);
            ((oracle.sql.BLOB) blob).trim(data.length);
            return blob;
```

this have a dependency to `oracle.sql.BLOB`. 
And if you use `org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate` you need add the explicit dependency to oracle driver in the quartz module definition, or alternatively add as resource the driver jar.

Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.quartz">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="quartz-2.2.1.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
        <module name="com.c3p0"/>
        <module name="com.oracle"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```